# Django Rest Framework: while using generics APIview I'm not able to set permissions( permissions.py not working for individual users)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want the admin user to access every user detail and the non-admin user to get access to its own detail only but Instead of this non-admin user is showing the full list of every user same as the admin user while implementing this. As I've shared my views.py, permissions.py, and models.py for the same.

I'm not sure whether the problem is in permisions.py or models.py as I'm new to Django.

I'm using Postman for API testing and this is working fine for the admin user but for an individual user, it's not working.

```
views.py


class UserListCreateAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsStaffOrTargetUser]
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class UserRetrtieveUpdateDestroyAPIView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsStaffOrTargetUser]
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

```
permissions.py

class IsStaffOrTargetUser(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        # allow user to list all users if logged in user is staff
        return request.user or request.user.is_staff
 
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # allow logged in user to view own details, allows staff to view all records
        return request.user.is_staff or obj == request.user
```

```
models.py

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Email',max_length=255,unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    contact_number= models.IntegerField()
    gender = models.IntegerField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    address= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pincode= models.IntegerField()
    dob = models.DateField(null= True)


    # is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name','contact_number','gender','address','state','city','country','pincode','dob']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin
```

Comment: Please add the traceback from the error you are receiving

Comment: Errors as in normal user are able to view all user detail in "UserListCreateAPIView".
and secondary I don't know how to add a traceback but I'll go through this and going to share that.